# While selecting value in choice column I am loosing : SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Mychoice =[];<br/>
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        var url = "https://xyz/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Approvers list')/items?$Select=Category"; <br/>
        $.ajax({  
        url: url,  <br/>
        headers: {  <br/>
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"  
        },  <br/>
        async: true,  
        success: function(data) {                   
            var items = data.d.results; <br/>
                $(items).each(function (index){
                    Mychoice.push(items[index].Category);<br/>
                    });<br/>
                    },  
            error: function () {<br/>
            console.log("Something went wrong");
                }                     
                });                    <br/>
            });         
            function myFunction1(){
            console.log(Mychoice);<br/>
            var select = document.getElementById("selectCategory"); <br/>

            select.innerHTML = "";<br/>
            for(var i = 0; i < Mychoice.length; i++) {
                var opt = Mychoice[i];<br/>
                select.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + opt + "\">" + opt + "</option>";<br/>
            }<br/>
            };<br/>

</script>


<script>
function UpdateItemStatus()
{
    console.log("Inside UpdateItemStatus function begin");
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("mylist");
var item;
var C1 = document.getElementById("selectCategory").value;
var C2= document.getElementById("ProvideComment").value;

for (item in selectedItems)
{

var mySelItem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[item].id);
<br/>

mySelItem.set_item("textfield",C1);<br/>
mySelItem.set_item("field2",C2);<br/>

mySelItem.update();<br/>
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailed));
}<br/>

}
<br/>
function onSucceeded() {
     console.log("succeeded");
}

function onFailed(sender, args) {
console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to add some information on your question so we better understand the issue and its context, thus helping to get accurate answers.

Comment: Hi @douvillema ..  myFunction1()  function creating a drop-down and the choice in drop-down is coming from another list.  on a button click  myFunction1()  runs and a default value appear in drop-down. If we leave the drop-down and submit the value , selected item get updated , but if changing drop-down , nothing happens.

Comment: What is your SharePoint version?

Comment: @douvillema  It's SharePoint 2013 enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Use IE F12 developer tools to check if some error messages occurs. And provide the information for further research.

I suggest you provide more details about how to reproduce this issue, others would get easier to research on it.